# How to set checked/unchecked functionality on Html table in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have an array of Json objects('filteredUsers' in below code) and I'm mapping them to a html table. Json object would look like {id: xyz, name: Dubov}

The below code would display a html table with a single column or basically a list. Each row will have name of user and a grey checkbox(unchecked) next to it initially. I want to select users in the table and when I select or click on any item in table, the checkmark has to turn green(checked).

```
            <table className="table table-sm">
              {this.state.filteredUsers && (
                <tbody>
                  {this.state.filteredUsers.map((user) => (
                    <tr key={user.id}>
                      <td onClick={() => this.selectUser(user)}>
                        
                        <span>{user.name}</span>               //Name

                        <div className={user.selected? "checked-icon": "unchecked-icon"}>   //Checkmark icon
                           <span class="checkmark"> </span>
                         </div>

                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  ))}
                </tbody>
              )}
            </table>
```

I tried setting a 'selected' key to each object. Initially object doesn't have 'selected' key so it will be false(all unchecked). I set onClick method for 'td' row which sets 'selected' key to object and sets it to true. Below function is called onClick of td or table item.

```
  selectUser = (user) => {
    user.selected = !user.selected;
  };
```

Now the issue is this will only work if I re-render the page after every onClick of 'td' or table item. And I'm forced to do an empty setState or this.forcedUpdate() in selectUser method to trigger a re-render. I read in multiple answers that a forced re-render is bad.

Any suggestions or help would be highly appreciated. Even a complete change of logic is also fine. My end goal is if I select an item, the grey checkmark has to turn green(checked) and if I click on it again it should turn grey(unchecked). Similarly for all items. Leave the CSS part to me, but help me with the logic. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe before you put the payload you got into the state (`filteredUsers`) you could use `.map()` and add a `selected` field to each user with the desired value.

Comment: @Eyal C The value of selected field keeps changing whenever I click on an item. How can I set it beforehand? I want the checked-unchecked feature in real time.

Comment: Please check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be a state issue.  When updating data in your react component, you'll need to make sure it's happening in one of two ways:

1. The data is updated by a component higher up in the tree and then is passed to this component via props.

   - this will cause your component to re-render with the new props and data, updating the "checked" property in your HTML.

In your case, it looks like you're using this second way:

2. The data is stored in component state.  Then, when you need to update the data, you'd do something like the below.

```js
const targetUser = this.state.filteredUsers.find(user => user.id === targetId)
const updatedUser = { ...targetUser, selected: !targetUser.selected }

this.setState({ filteredUsers: [ ...this.state.filteredUsers, updatedUser ] })
```

Updating your state in this way will trigger an update to your component.  Directly modifying the state object without using `setState` does not trigger the update.

Please keep in mind that, when updating objects in component state, you'll need to pass a **new, full object** to `setState` in order to trigger the update.  Something like this will not work: `this.setState({ filteredUsers[1].selected: false });`

[Relevant documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

Comment: It gives me an error. **"this.state.filteredUsers.map is not a function"**. I don't understand how you're adding the update user object back to state.

Comment: That's because I was treating `filteredUsers` as an object when it looks like it's an array.  Your error comes from later in your code when you attempt to run the `.map` function on your new object which doesn't have that function.

I've updated my answer so it treats `filteredUsers` as an array instead`

Comment: this method is adding the same users again to the array with a selected key. We need a way to add the selected property to existing user object or replace the existing one with updateduser.

Comment: I intentionally did not provide the exact code needed to make this work for you.  My solution is designed to help you understand React state updates so that you can then write your own code in the way that makes best sense for you.

The state update is what's required here.  If the code you're using isn't updating the state correctly, please do check out the relevant documentation link I provided.  It should help you understand state updates better and how to properly implement them.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
const Users = () => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch users from the API when the component mounts
    api.getUsers().then((users) => {
      // Add a `selected` field to each user and store them in state
      setUsers(users.map((user) => ({ ...user, selected: true })))
    })
  }, [])

  const toggleUserSelected = (id) => {
    setUsers((oldUsers) =>
      oldUsers.map((user) =>
        user.id === id ? { ...user, selected: !user.selected } : user
      )
    )
  }

  return (
    <ul>
      {users.map((user) => (
        <li key={user.id} onClick={() => toggleUserSelected(user.id)}>
          <span>{user.name}</span>

          <div className={user.selected ? "checked-icon" : "unchecked-icon"}>
            <span class="checkmark" />
          </div>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  )
}
```

I've used hooks for this but the principles are the same.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Can you please write the setState equivalent of the 'setUsers' hook. I'm not much familiar with hooks concepts.

Comment: The equivalent of `setUsers(newUsers)` would be `this.setState({ users: newUsers })`